# Animated Deep Zoom-in. (Drone style)

Tags: animation

New guy here, 
My question is of a workflow nature. I am trying to animate a "fly-in" zoom shot (similar to the shot in Sintel) that zooms in from the air over a landscape ultimately down to a close up of the character's face, much like a shot from a drone.
 Would a good workflow be to do it in several .blends getting more detail in each one progressively while deleting more and more geometry as well, or, to try and do it in one .blend file?

Comment: Hi Jay welcome to the Blender stack exchange.  If this is a single, long zoom-in shot you're talking about, I think one .blend file would work.   Are you concerned that the .blend will get too big?

Comment: Just concerned it will take forever to render the300 frames or so, because it is a heavily wooded mountainous landscape. Trees done with particles. (either bilboard UV, or low poly tree shapes) Zoom in to a clearing with the character climbing.... all the way close to his face. I got several progressively increasing detailed (from low poly to high) characters to replace the previous one as the zoom shot closes in.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the render time of a large scale scene like that there is a nice new option for object camera culling (Cycles only).

It will remove the visibility of objects from the scene as they move outside of the camera's view, saving rendering computation. If the object moves back in frame the object comes back. It only does this for rendering. The objects will not actually be removed in your .blend file or 3D viewport.

1. Switch to the Cycles render engine
2. In the Properties panel go to the Scene tab.
3. Check the box for Simplify

[image: The properties panel's scene tab with Simplify and Use Camera Cull options checked.]

Then select an individual object:

1. Go to the object properties panel
2. Expand the Cycles Settings section
3. Check Use Camera Cull

[image: An objects' properties with "Use Camera Cull" option selected under the Cycles settings for that object.]

**Warning:** You will have to deal with problems like having shadows and reflections suddenly disappear from the camera's view, because the culling only detects the actual object in the camera's view; not any of its influence (shadows, reflections, etc) on the rest of the scene. Some of this could be fixed using the "Camera Cull Margin" option near the "Use Camera Cull" option in the scene properties (Image 1). The rest will have to be fixed by just being selective about which object you check the cull option on.

Comment: Thanks I think that will help a lot. I didn't know about this option for the camera. I have the camera tracking to a curve, and lots of great looking trees on a billboard particle system, but last night it took all night to render 20 frames. Maybe culling will help.

Comment: @JayMcAllister No problem! I wouldn't expect miracles from just culling, but it should help. Don't forget to give my answer some points if you think it deserves them! Go to blender.stackexchange.com/tour if you're not familiar with how Stack Exchange works.